# how to put html inside script tag and show it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please is it possible to load some HTML element inside script tag and access any one of it using the class name

```
<script id="scripttags">
    <div class="item-1">Hello</div>
    <div class="item-2">Hello2</div>
    <div class="item-3">Hello</div>
</script>
```

**Access it:**

```
<script>
    var loadit = $('script#scripttags item-2').clone();
    alert(loadit);
<script>
```

Please is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: erm what... why? script is for js - not html

Comment: You can;t put html element in script tag instead you can append html dynamically if u want

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs yes i know that why i want to load my html inside then access it using the id or class name

Comment: Why do you want to do like this?

Comment: why not just assign the html as a js string variable and use `.html(htmlVar)` ?

Comment: The javascript for cloning the html element is fine. What you want to do is put your html "template" code inside a div tag, not a script tag. So you would have <div id="scripttags"></div> and inside this div you can just put your other html content.

Comment: You can create these elements as normal html element and set it's CSS display:none, and you can access those div elements like $('.item-1')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use handlebars but it also can be done with pure js/jquery:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script id="scripttags" type="text/html">
        <div class="item-1">Hello</div>
        <div class="item-2">Hello2</div>
        <div class="item-3">Hello</div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var el = $( '<div></div>' );
        el.html($('#scripttags').text());
        var loadit = el.find('.item-2').html();
        alert(loadit);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I put the content of your script tag in a dynamically created div and at this moment it behaves like normal DOM

Answer (score 0):

Use handlebars.js to create template. Bind it to json data after compilation. Then, you can show html. You can also use other templating libraries like mustache.js, underscore.js template etc.

The code below is from
http://handlebarsjs.com

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
<div class="entry"> 
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
 <div class="body">
 {{body}} 
</div> 
</div> 
</script>
```

This defined the template. Then, you can use it as shown below.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var source = $("#entry-template").html(); 
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"}; 
    var html = template(context);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$("body").html(
   '<div class="item-1">
     Hello
    </div>

    <div class="item-2">
    Hello2
    </div>

    <div class="item-3">
    Hello3
    </div>'
  );
```

Here, in the `body` the desired alement can be added/assigned/appended.